# permit a user to access a selected folder only (Active directory 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions

I add the user in the Global Security Group (IT Dept), and create a folder and add the IT Dept in security permission on it.

Under security tab of the folder, I want to remove the Machine\Users group (because this allows users to access the folder), but when I hit the remove button, a message 
"You cannot remove ....because this object is inheriting permission to its parent" pop up.

If I click on the 'ADVANCED' button, what should I need to check or uncheck to allow me to remove the Machine\Users group?

What is the right setup to do in making a folder accessible to a specific group only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the newly created directory from inheriting NTFS permissions from its parent directory.

To do that, you should uncheck the **Allow inheritable permissions from parent to propagate to this object** checkbox. You will then be prompted whether to **Copy** the parent directory's permissions to your new directory, or to **Remove** all permissions. You can then remove the ACL entry referring to **MACHINE\Users**.

See [MS KB313398](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313398) for more info.

Comment: undertand. but when i uncheck the 'Allow inheritable permissions from parent to propagate to this object' all user access (Administrators, CREATOR OWNER, SYSTEM) have been removed also.only the Global Security Group - IT Dept has remain. Do i continue to uncheck the 'allow inheriatable...'

Comment: When you uncheck, you could select **Copy** to keep the existing permissions, then just remove those you don't want to keep. It sounds like you selected to **Remove** when you unchecked.

Comment: this is what i did: i select MACHINE\User then select ADVANCED, uncheck the 'allow inheritable...' choose COPY.  and then I can now remove the MACHINE\USER.. but still, the Folder is accessible to All users even they are not belong to the Secutiry Group i assigned to the Folder.

Comment: Then the users must be members of some other group which does have permission. Can you put a screenshot in your question?

Comment: yeah! you really offer a big help.. but when can i send you the screenshots?

Comment: where can i send the screenshots? Thanks!

Comment: Edit your original question and click the "Image" button to upload it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Sharing" tab enable to share it and either leave the share name alone or change it to whatever. Under the permissions (Permission button?) remove everyone in there. Add the user, "Authenticated Users" and then click all of the check boxes except full control I believe it's Read and Write only.

On the "Security" tab uncheck the box to inherit from parent and click "COPY" when it asks. Then remove "Creator Owner" and click Apply/OK.

Try this. You must share the folder in order for it to be accessed. There are ways around that, but for this we'll keep it simple.

Comment: I follow your instruction, unfortunately, this not solve my problem. Is there any other way?. I think my security Group is not working properly, when I created a Sales Folder and add MIS_Group but i cheked the DENY permission for MIS, still, it can access the Sales Folder.

Comment: Take some screen captures of the permissions of the Sales folder and all of the tabs and post them here so I can see exactly how you have everything configured.